# How do you map areas on icon set to buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, button, icons, css-sprites

I want to use a login button set ([courtesy of Komodo Media](http://www.komodomedia.com/download/#sign-in-with-twitter-facebook-and-openid)) for my ASP.NET MVC3 website and assign the icons to the corresponding buttons, but the button set is a single image:
[image]
Aside from going in with an image editor and splitting the icons out into separate image files, is there a way to do it with code? I know that a similar thing is done with the stackoverflow markup buttons, but I don't know how to do the same thing programatically (not sure of the proper term either):
[image]

What's the proper way to "map" the different parts of image to separate buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). Scott Hansleman [blogged](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx) about it. Personally I have been using the [Sprite and Image Optimization framework](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/65787) in many projects.

For example in Razor you could simply use the following helper:

```
@Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/facebook.png")
```

which will render the correct image from the single Sprite using CSS background positioning technique.

Comment: After going through the documentation, it seems that I will still have to split the image into separate icons and let the Sprite and Image Optimization framework generate the sprites for me. I just wanted to point out for anybody else viewing this answer that you start with multiple icons and the framework generates a single sprite for you.

Answer (score 1):

CSS backgrounds are how it's done.

http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/css-background-image-sprites-a-beginners-guide-/