# How to create an ActionImage from a CSS Sprite

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, css-sprites

This is a follow up on my previous question: [How do you map areas on icon set to buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948955/how-do-you-map-areas-on-icon-set-to-buttons)

I decided to make my own `HtmlHelper` extension in order to create an `ActionImage` link, so I cannibalized some of the popular extensions posted on SO and got this:

```
// Controller/Action Image Link
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, 
    string controller, string action, object routeValues, 
    string imageSrc, string alternateText, object imageAttributes)
{
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    // build the <img> tag
    TagBuilder imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
    imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imageSrc));
    imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alternateText", alternateText);
    string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

    // build the <a> tag
    TagBuilder anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
    anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
    string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
}
```

Now, the problem is that I have a CSS Sprite with and I don't know how to make it work with the `ActionImage` extension method:

```
@Html.ActionImage("Account", "LogOn", null, Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/twitterlogin.png"), "", null)
```

I tried calling the `ToString()` method of the sprite, but it doesn't return the URL. Is there another way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass just the path to the sprite:

```
@Html.ActionImage(
    "Account", 
    "LogOn", 
    null, 
    "~/App_Sprites/twitterlogin.png", 
    "", 
    null
)
```

and then have the helper take care of generating the image using the `Sprite.Image` helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, 
    string controller, string action, object routeValues, 
    string imageSrc, string alternateText, object imageAttributes)
{
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

    // build the <img> tag
    string img = Sprite.Image(imageSrc).ToHtmlString();

    // build the <a> tag
    TagBuilder anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
    anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
    string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
}
```